# What happens when the concurrencyLevel is greater that the capacity of a ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have been scratching my head around a question for some time now, I have looked around but have failed at finding the answer. I want to know what will happen if the `concurrencyLevel` will be greater than the `capacity` of the Map.

By default both are 16 which means that each bucket will have a lock. And if the `capacity` will be 32 and `concurrencyLevel` 16 that a lock will be held on 2 buckets. But what happens when `concurrencyLevel` is 32 and `capacity` is 16?

Will each bucket be held by 2 locks, then what happens if the distribution of `concurrencyLevel` and `capacity` is uneven, like 24 and 16, or something?

Comment: at times I wish SO had a feature to tag people you know would have the answer so that you get an immediate response, a feature similar to quora but more refined, like I can tag the people who have already commented in the post.

Comment: That's what tags are for, and @pings in comments.

Comment: yeah! but can I tag anyone in SO community, even without them commenting on the question? @oleg will this work?

Comment: @rd22: Last I know you could tag anyone in the community that way but it is highly discouraged. I remember there was a meta question where one of the answerer was particularly angry because he felt he was 'summoned' for answering a question.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing special happens. Did you check the documentation of `ConcurrentHashMap`? It says: “Also, for compatibility with previous versions of this class, constructors may optionally specify an expected `concurrencyLevel` as an additional hint for internal sizing.” It’s a hint, not a limitation. Furthermore on `concurrencyLevel`: “the estimated number of concurrently updating threads. The implementation may use this value as a sizing hint.” Note: “may”. So if anything happens, the size becomes different. Maybe.

If you want further implementation details, you may study the source code. It’s available. In Java 1.8 it contanis the following two lines:

```
    if (initialCapacity < concurrencyLevel)   // Use at least as many bins
        initialCapacity = concurrencyLevel;   // as estimated threads
```

Comment: This makes sense, I verified it from the source, but I was working in java 7 and it was not clear in java 7, they had used too many internal variables. Does something similar happens Java 7?